# Unable to call the JS Interface In Android Web View

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to get video URL of Web view  . Through some googling i find some solution to get video URL . But if i get the Facebook video url , then nothing to work , no video url is coming , even JS interface is not called.I am describing my code below , please suggest me that its right procedure and if yes then how i call JS Interface. Thanks in advance.

```
      web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
      web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      web.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

      web.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(this), "imageClick");
      web.loadUrl("my url");
```

On touch method

```
    float x,y;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //In response to the picture on the web click event by wenview touch    
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; //Screen density
                float touchX = event.getX() / density;  //Must be divided by the density of the screen
                float touchY = event.getY() / density;
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    x = touchX;
                    y = touchY;
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    float dx = Math.abs(touchX-x);
                    float dy = Math.abs(touchY-y);
                    if(dx<10.0/density&&dy<10.0/density){
                        clickImage(touchX,touchY);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

    private void clickImage(float touchX, float touchY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String js = "javascript:(function(){" +
                        "var  obj=document.elementFromPoint("+touchX+","+touchY+");"
                        +"if(obj.src!=null){"+"window.imageClick.click(obj.src);}" +   
                    "})()";

                web.loadUrl(js);
            }
```

JS Interface

```
  class JsInterface{
            Context context;

            public JsInterface(Context context){
                this.context = context;
            }

            //See the picture URL
             @JavascriptInterface
            public void click(String url){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you set onTouch listener to webview?

Comment: yes , touch is working , in js string i got thie javascript:(function(){var  obj=document.elementFromPoint(268.62692,15.903198);if(obj.src!=null){window.imageClick.click(obj.src);}})()

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: no trying ang gooling to find solution

Comment: i tried your code is working!!

Comment: on click image , i want to get video url but not getting..and i am unable to convert js into string , so that i get the url of video

Comment: can you post your url let i check?

Comment: can you give me mail id , so that i will mail you..

Comment: I am not asking entire project or code. the url you used in webview.loadUrl(url).

Comment: i am taking facebook .com url , but not get the video url , but getting all videos url, please check

Comment: hello Arun , are you solved the issue , i want to get the facebook video or image url. I have checked other url , and video link is easily coming.

Comment: hi @Praveen Rawat i am very close to get facebook video url.

Comment: @arun thanks , please tell me when completed.

Comment: hi @PraveenRawat check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His code to get the facebook video is

> String js = "javascript:(function(){" +
>                   "var obj = document.elementFromPoint(" +touchX+", "+touchY+");" 
>                   + "if(obj.src!=null){"
>                   + "window.imageClick.click(obj.src);
> }})()";

Here is the structure of post in facebook (you can inspect this from browser)

> <parent div>   
>     header div 
>     <image>
>   etc..

==> parent div has the data-store. **data-store** contains the detail of the video like id, src, etc.,

==> This image tag is display first (after we click the image the video source will load)

Like this:

> <div **data-store="{\"videoId\":\"234423545343\",...\"src\" :\"video_url\"..">**
>   <header tag/>
>   <i class=\"\"/>
>   <footer tag/>
>   </div>

here problem is when click the image we get only image tag. In image tag we can't get the source of the video (**That is the mistake**). because it store the detail on parent tag. **So I fix the issue by getting the parent element and check whether it has data-store, If means get the url from the data-store value json.**

> "var datastore = obj.parentElement;"
>               + "var ds = datastore.attributes[1].name;"
>               +"if(ds == 'data-store'){"
>               +"window.imageClick.click(datastore.attributes[1].value);}"

Try this to get a video in facebook. I added full code here.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.timer.WebActivity.JsInterface;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    WebView wb;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web1);

        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.setOnTouchListener(this);
        wb.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/The.Most.Amazing.Videos?ref=bf");
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

        });
        wb.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(Web1Activity.this), "imageClick");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    class JsInterface{
        Context context;

        public JsInterface(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        //See the picture URL
         @JavascriptInterface
        public void click(String json){
             Log.i("json", json);
             try {
                JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);
                String url = job.getString("src");
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"called" + url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                 Log.i("url", url);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Intent intent = new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("url", url);
            //startActivity(intent);              
        }
    } 

     float x,y;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //In response to the picture on the web click event by wenview touch    
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; //Screen density
        float touchX = event.getX() / density;  //Must be divided by the density of the screen
        float touchY = event.getY() / density;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x = touchX;
            y = touchY;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            float dx = Math.abs(touchX-x);
            float dy = Math.abs(touchY-y);
            if(dx<10.0/density&&dy<10.0/density){
                clickImage(touchX,touchY);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clickImage(float touchX,float touchY)
    {
      String js = "javascript:(function(){" +
            "var  obj=document.elementFromPoint("+touchX+","+touchY+");"
            +"var datastore = obj.parentElement;"
            + "var ds = datastore.attributes[1].name;"                
            +"if(ds == 'data-store'){"
            +"window.imageClick.click(datastore.attributes[1].value);}"    +                  
        "})()";

     wb.loadUrl(js);
    }    
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ,.you realy saved me , and this question will help many people , i am sure .can i asked where i am wrong.

Comment: Actually i am newbie in stack over flow , so i cant make 0 to 1 :-) , but i mark  its best answer.

Comment: Can you add some explanation what you changed? What was the problem